Lightning Data Table Rows are Hiding Picklist Custom Data Type Dropdown Menu
I am trying to implement a new lightning data table LWC, and I want to add a few picklist custom data types to some of the table cells. The picklists render correctly. However, the dropdown menu for each picklist is hidden behind the table row. How would I change the style for the picklist data type component so that the dropdown menu is visible? I have attached a screenshot of the current state of the picklist in the table cell for reference.


Unfortunately there isn't currently an answer for this.  There's a few questions though:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/422848/extended-datatable-custom-picklist-dropdown-is-being-hidden  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330654/lwc-datatable-picklist-dropdown-is-hiding-below
